# Can't load JS static file, but style.css file still work

Tags: javascript, django, django-staticfiles

This is my error. The styles.css and index.js file in same folder name network. But the styles.css file is work, and index.js file doesn't work, it looking to my other project is Mail

```
[20/Feb/2022 14:17:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1804
[20/Feb/2022 14:17:59] "GET /static/network/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[20/Feb/2022 14:18:01] "GET /static/mail/inbox.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1667
[20/Feb/2022 14:18:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1804
```

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

index.html

```html
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'network/index.js' %}" defer></script>
{% endblock %}
```

index.js

```js
console.log('OK');
```

layout.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Social Network{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: Try adding this in your `settings.py`:
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]` also import `os` if not there.

Comment: Where is network/layout.html file?

Comment: Thank you @rain , I tried it before and nothing happen !

Comment: @eisanahardani network/templates/network/layout.html. I just update layout.html file above, pls check, thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `block script` in layout.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Social Network{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>

      {% block script %}
      {% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: and you know why it sill get /static/mail/inbox.js ?. This is from my another project "Mail" !
`code
[21/Feb/2022 09:27:52] "GET /static/mail/inbox.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1667
`

Comment: Sorry, i need more information including file tree. do you use `include` tag in your network application in order to including mail template?

Answer (score 0):

add type to script and try it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "network/index.js" %}"></script>
```

Comment: nothing happen !